# Как просмотреть всё содержимое .sql файла в 1ГБ?

Tags: файлы, sql

Как просмотреть всё содержимое .sql файла в 1ГБ?

Любые браузеры и текстовые редакторы виснут.

Comment: импортировать куда-нибудь, например в БД, и уже с помощью неё смотреть то, что нужно. А вы через блокнотик смотрите? :D Ну попробуйте notepad++, у меня спокойно открывает файлы весом 500мб.

Comment: lister в Totalcmd

Comment: Еще можно порезать на пару-тройку файлов приемлимого размера.

Comment: @lampa, проблема в том, что импортируется 3 таблицы из 6. Вот я хочу и заглянуть в сам файл, может там действительно 3 таблицы. Нотепад ошибку выбивает.

Comment: [MultiEdit](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiEdit)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вы ведь не хотите просмотреть весь гигабайт данных, правда? То есть вам и не нужно открывать такой файл.

Вы скорее всего хотели запустить в файле поиск, правильно? Это можно сделать и не открывая файл редактором, для этого существуют более адекватные средства, например, `grep`.

Eсли вы хотите всего лишь узнать, сколько там таблиц, вам нужно что-то вроде

```
grep -i "CREATE TABLE" /path/to/sql
```

(Чтобы посмотреть первые 100 строк и увидеть, как там описана первая таблица, используйте `sed 100q /path/to/sql`.)

Comment: что бы посмотреть первые сто строк, нужно использовать head -n 100.

Comment: сдается мне, что у ТС идет речь о windows ;) а вообще линух  не виснет на таких файлах :)

Comment: @KoVadim: `sed 100q` тоже работает, [известная](http://www.techinterviews.com/basic-sed-tricks) же идиома.

Answer (score 7):

Встроенный просмотрщик в FAR открывает любые файлы **моментально**, так как он их не читает полностью при открытии, а считывает нужные части файла по мере просмотра.

Answer (score 5):

Так нужно просто пользоваться правильными текстовыми редакторами! В свое время пользовался [emeditor](http://www.emeditor.com/). 200-400 Мб открывал с пол пинка.

Но если по правильному, то такие файлы обычно смотрят в консоли с помощью less, grep и компании.

Comment: @KoVadim, как использовать то? less </var/www/user1734_modal/data/www/montytool.com/bigdump.sql> отклоняет

Comment: less /var/www/user1734_modal/data/www/montytool.com/bigdump.sql

угловые скобки не нужны.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте [less](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less)

Comment: @Zhukov Roman, как использовать то? less </var/www/user1734_modal/data/www/montytool.com/bigdump.sql> отклоняет

Comment: @Modal, поподробнее, как это less отклоняет?

Что говорит?

Answer (score 3):

Если дело происходит в Unix системе можно открыть из шелла
выполнив

> head -<число строк для
> отображения> <имя файла>

получите указанное количество строк текста из файла с начала.
хотите с конца - замените `head` на `tail`

Answer (score 2):

notepad++ спокойно открывает такие файлы

Comment: @levantez, нет. Пишет, что размер файла слишком большой для открытия.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение про FAR скажу, что mcedit из Midnight Commander работает аналогично. Последний раз большой дамп просматривал именно с его помощью.

Answer (score 1):

Под какой платформой вы пытаетесь это сделать, Windows или Linux?
В любом случае если вас интересует только просмотр, а не редактирования, лучше использовать просмотр а не редактирование.
В windows в Total commander или Far
В Linux mightnight commander.
Ну или как советовали консольные средства поиска. findstr в windows grep в linux.
Кстати в linux меня приятно удивил vim для редактирования больших файлов. Открыл файл в 400~ мб практически мгновенно. Так понимаю это связано с тем что он не пытается загрузить сразу всю информация в оперативную память, в отличии от большинства других текстовых редакторов.